# Firefox is not loading my ui-view

Tags: firefox, uiview, angular-ui-router

people:

I'm using ui.router in my page and Firefox is not loading the views.

This is the config:

```
.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
        .state('inicio', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/templates/principal.html'
        })

        .state('tienda', {
            url: '/tienda',
            templateUrl: 'templates/tienda2.html'
        })

        .state('carrito', {
            url: '/carrito',
            templateUrl: 'templates/carrito.html'
        })

        .state('contacto', {
            url: '/contacto',
            templateUrl: 'templates/contacto.html'
        })
```

In the html, I'm using the  tag for the section where I want the views to appear and ui-sref attribute on the navbar but Firefox shows them as if they were paragraphs.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-custom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
              <a ui-sref="inicio"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>  PRINCIPAL</a></li>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a ui-sref="tienda"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>  TIENDA</a></li>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a ui-sref="carrito"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>  CARRITO</a></li>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a ui-sref="contacto"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>  CONTACTO</a></li>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Ingresar</button>
    </div>
  </nav>


<div class="container">
   <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

This is the code as of now. In chrome works wonderfully, yet Firefox doesn't recognize the ui-sref at all.

Comment: Can you explain more where / how your `ui-view` is set up? Also, you are registering 2 different states on the same URL with the same template?

Comment: Actually, Firefox is the ONLY browser that does that. The views work even on IE.